# Lowering the order of a linear differential equation

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

Let

$$L(x) \equiv x^{(n)}+a_1(t)x^{(n-1)}+...+a_{n-1}(t)x'+a_n(t)x=0.$$

and let the following solutions be given: $x_1,x_2,...,x_m(m<n)$- linear independent solutions. Let's find: $x_{m+1}, x_{m+2},....,x_n$

$$x=x_1 \int ydt \\ x'=x_1'\int y dt +x_1 y \\ .... \\ x^{(n)}=x_1^{(n)}\int y dt+...+x_1y^{(n-1)}$$
I dont know what, or how this above comes about. Then, again don't understand:

$$x_1y^{(n-1)}+A_1(t)y^{(n-2)}+A_{n-1}(t)y+(x_1(t)^{(n)}+a_1(t)x_1^{(n-1)}+...+a_{n-1}(t)x_1'+a_n(t)x)\cdot\int ydt=0\\ $$

Can anyone see why this is, or has come across this  before ?

Answer (score 2):

Let's look at the second order case first:

$x''+ax'+bx=0$ and $x_{1}$ is a solution. Then, we seek a $v$ such that $x_{2}=x_{1}v$ is a solution. The requirement is then that

$(x_{1}'v+x_{1}v')'+a(x_{1}'v+x_{1}v')+bx_{1}v=0\Rightarrow $

$x_{1}''v+x_{1}v'+x_{1}'v'+x_{1}v''+a(x_{1}'v+x_{1}v')+bx_{1}v=0\Rightarrow $

$v(x_{1}''+ax_{1}'+bx_{1})+v'(x_{1}'+ax_{1})+v''x_{1}=0\Rightarrow $

$\frac{v''}{v'}=-\frac{(x_{1}'+ax_{1})}{x_{1}}\Rightarrow $

$v=\int \left ( \exp-\left ( \frac{(x_{1}'+ax_{1})}{x_{1}} \right ) \right )dt$

and this, in principle, determines $x_2$.

Now, for the general case, suppose $x_1$ is a solution. It is tedious but routine to show that $x_2=x_1v$ is another solution, where $v$ is determined as in the second order case. Continuing in this way, if $x_1, \cdots , x_m, $ are solutions, we can obtain another solution $x_{m+1}=x_mv_m$ using the same procedure. There is, of course, the question of linear independence of the solutions which needs to be addressed, but this is fairly routine as well.